# web2py db is not defined

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to run a script at command line that uses the models with the following command:

```
c:\web2py>python web2py.py -M -N -S automate -R applications/automate/modules/eventserver.py
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2011
Version 1.99.7 (2012-03-04 22:12:08) stable
Database drivers available: SQLite3, pymysql, pg8000, IMAP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\web2py\gluon\shell.py", line 206, in run
    execfile(startfile, _env)
  File "applications/automate/modules/eventserver.py", line 6, in <module>
    deviceHandler = devicehandler.DeviceHandler()
  File "applications\automate\modules\devicehandler.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.devices = self.getActiveDevices()
 File "applications\automate\modules\devicehandler.py", line 18, in getActiveDe
vices
    print db
NameError: global name 'db' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: From my research I have only found the solution "add -M to your command" but I've already done that and it still doesnt work.

edit2: I have db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite') in my db.py so it should get loaded

Comment: *"global name 'db' is not defined"*

Comment: Why am I getting downrated? What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> edit2: I have db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite') in my db.py so it should get loaded

Assuming db.py is in the /models folder, the `db` object created there will be available in later executed model files as well as in the controller and view, but it will not be available within modules that you import. Instead, you will have to pass the `db` object to a function or class in the module. Another option is to add the `db` object to the `current` thread local object, which can then be imported and accessed within the module:

In /models/db.py:

```
from gluon import current
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
current.db = db
```

In /modules/eventserver.py:

```
from gluon import current
def somefunction():
    db = current.db
    [do something with db]
```

Note, if you do define the `db` object in the module, don't define it at the top level -- define it in a function or class.

For more details, see the book section on [modules and `current`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules).

Comment: I understand. I will try this when I get off work. Thanks alot for the  help! :)

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution but I get the error `<class 'psycopg2.InterfaceError'> cursor already closed` any ideas?

Comment: Can you show some code (maybe open a new question, here or on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py))?

Comment: Hi, I have two case scenarios:
1. A function in the module is being used withing the application by a controller, in that case the first time db is use it is fine and the second time I get this error `<class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'> no results to fetch`
2. The function the module is being used in another application's controller and the second time db is used gives me `<class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'> no results to fetch`

Comment: All the condition you mentioned in your solution is in place and the signature of the function in the module looks like `def is_self_or_parent(user, client, db=current.db)` I fixed my second case by passing the db but I don't know why the first case doesn't just work with current.db!

Comment: Instead of defaulting the `db` argument to `current.db`, perhaps try defaulting to `db=None`, and then in the function body, you can do `if db is None: db = current.db`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, if I set db to current.db inside the function it will not complain. what is the reason though? does this has anything to do with python interpreter early interpretation of that function argument?

Comment: `current` is a thread local object (unique to each thread). You don't want to assign it to a variable at the top level in a module, as that variable will then forever reference the version from the original thread. Instead, you want to assign it within functions or methods so the value will be set per thread at the time of execution.

Comment: I keep getting AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'db'

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without seeing any code. I suggest you open a new question or post to the web2py Google Group.