# Why do I get a 'NameError' with this import?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-import

I'm building a web app that uses Flask and SQLAlchemy, but I can't seem to see the reason why this won't import correctly and work.

I'm trying to test my database that I'm building, but I keep getting a `NameError`:

File1:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
from File2 import db, data1, data2, data3
```

File2:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///DB_File.db' # Uses '///' because '////' puts the file in '/' on server.
db.SQLAlchemy(app)
```

File2 is followed by some classes that inherit `db.Model`, but I don't think I need to include these in here.

To get the error, I'm pulling up a Python interpreter and doing `import File1`. This looks like:

```
>>> import File1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Tux/code/AppName/app/Util/File1.py", line 6, in <module>
    from KarmaCourtDB import db, data1, data2, data3
  File "/Tux/code/AppName/app/Util/File2.py", line 6, in <module>
    db.SQLAlchemy(app)
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction! This code was working before and I could create the database by using `db.create_all()` after importing it.

Comment: `db.SQLAlchemy(app)` should almost certainly be `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.SQLAlchemy(app)` is not defining `db`, and is only attempting to run a `SQLAlchemy()` method on `db`.
  `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` however, would define `db`.

Comment: I realized that I missed that this morning after some sleep, but you are correct. I really need to stop development when I reach a certain level of sleep deprivation.

Comment: @Tux It happens to all of us :)